# sklearn BayesianGaussianMixture Cluster assignment based on more than one data point

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-computing, gaussian, bayesian, mixture

I am trying to using sklearn.mixture.BayesianGaussianMixture to fit a set of trajectories.

Each trajectory consists of a set of data points, e.g.

```
t_i = {x_i1, y_i1, x_i2, y_i2, ... , x_iN, y_iN},
```

where `t_i` is the ith trajectory and `(x_ik, y_ik)` is the k-th point on the trajectory. For example, x_ik could represent the state of a robot at time step k, and y_ik could represent the action taken by the robot. 
Each GP component will be a mapping from x_ik -> y_ik. That's quite standard for learning a GP using sklearn.

However, when you want to learn a Gaussian Mixture model with Dirichlet Process prior, you have to decide **when a new GP component will be added**.

The **BayesianGaussianMixture** class only provides you an interface to do cluster assignment based on a single data point. In other words, whether a new data point belongs to a new cluster or not.

What I am interested in is that: Give a set of trajectories, where each trajectory might contain a lot of data points. Is there a way to do cluster assignment based on the trajectory? i.e. Given a new trajectory, decide whether it belongs to a new cluster or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the following approach.

At first, try to convert your continuous coordinates to a set of discrete values. For example, you can divide your map into cells and assign to each point (x_i, y_i) a label, based on a cell. In this case, each trajectory becomes a sequence of labels

```
traj_1: cell_id_0 -> cell_id_1 -> ... -> cell_id_n
traj_2: cell_id_3 -> cell_id_6 -> ... -> cell_id_m
...
```

Now it is possible to use something like [bag-of-words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) or [word2vec](http://mccormickml.com/2016/04/19/word2vec-tutorial-the-skip-gram-model/) to represent each trajectory (presumably of different length) with a fixed set of features, or, in the other words, as a **singe point** in high-dimensional space. There might be a simpler way, but I am not aware of it.

Comment: @MinChen I think that it doesn't matter a lot, at least from theoretical point of view. Practically, it will complicate the procedure of assigning discrete labels to each data point. I'm not able to give any advises here, it requires diving into the problem itself.